# PrimeNG Dynamic Dialog - Close by click to nowhere

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-dialog

I use a [Dynamic Dialog](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dynamicdialog) from PrimeNG.

How can I force to close the dialog by clicking in the "nowhere" area around the dialog?
Currently I only can close the dialog by using buttons within the dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dismissableMask` property to do that.

`dismissableMask` property specifices if clicking the modal background should hide the dialog.

```
    this.dialogService.open(ProductListDemo, {
        header: 'Choose a Product',
        width: '70%',
        contentStyle: {"max-height": "500px", "overflow": "auto"},
        baseZIndex: 10000,
        dismissableMask: true
    });
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks :)